# Is there a good guide/mind map for factors of quantitative trading?

Tags: factor-models

I have know there are many factors , they can divied into several groups in my opinion

- group 1 are some factors called  `P/E` , `P/B`, `ROE` ....  , used to describe a company's history/current status .
- group 2 are factors called `MA5`, `MA12` , `MACD`  .... , these are calculated from the stock values
- group 3 something called alpha factors , a big familly , are calculated through some complicated formula

I mean, is there some good guide or mind map can:

- cover most of them
- tell what are them, how they come from
- tell how they divided
- tell how they used for

I searched around and nothing useful found , every site I found only described some of them and talking in their way . For what I saw , there are at least 20+ in group 1 , 100+ in group 2 . 200+ in group 3

Comment: I think your definition is mixing factors vs characteristics  which is an often overlooked but important distinction.

Comment: I like the term Return Predictive Signals (RPS) used by Green, Hand and Zhang. It is very broad and includes macroeconomic variables, company characteristics (which might be divided into fundamental and price based (technical, i.e your Group 2)) and factors (in the FamaFrench sense).

Comment: There is no characteristics mentioned here just confusion, over basic finance theory, and RPS have little to do with factors of APT, which is where factors come into play, they are not signals.

Comment: This really is ludicrous someone asks a rhetorical question about finance which is completely incorrect on every count, and gets a plus, two completely irrelevant comments, on nonsense get plus, I correct the recored with true financeand economic theory and get double markdown what a farce, this is a joke.

Comment: I do not know what la la land was happening when this was written  "I searched around ... , every site I found only ... some of them ... their way . For what I saw , there are at least 20+ (?)in group 1 , 100+ in group 2 (?). 200+ in group 3"(???). 2 is not a factor but technical trading signals they are not related with alpha . 3 Alpha  is the intercept of the market security line not a factor, seeking alpha or positive returns, when beta is isolated, you need to buy a text on Investment Science such as Luenberger rather than display a completely confused and incorrect knowledge .